# regexp: match everything beginning from second dot including dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match everything beginning from second `.`, including `.`

Regexp: `/(?<=\d\.\d+)\..*/g`. Playground [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3IELC2/2)

It does not work for strings `1232..233232`.

Comment: You should include the language tag you're working in. Different languages have different regex engines. JavaScript for example doesn't allow a look-behind.

Comment: @3limin4t0r [JS supports a lookbehind](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-whats-new-in-ecmascript-2018-es2018-17ede97f36d5#ca4f) starting with ECMAScript 2018. Chrome supports it.

Comment: Harshvardhan, you should explain what you are doing. These recent questions of yours indicate you are having some interesting problem - why not explain it? BTW, in JS, to get all after the second dot can be obtained without any lookbehind, `s.match(/\.[^.]*(\..*)/)[1]`, see https://regex101.com/r/QMDN4N/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I will post a new question that explains my problem A-Z

Comment: Seems like this issue is your typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

as @WiktorStribiżew points out the regex don't test for `1212.2e1.121212` os this might be a better solution.

`/(?<=^[^.]*\.[^.]*)\..*/` since it will also test for this

#### old answer.

You can do this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3IELC2/7), this will begin including from the second `.` including it.

Regexp: `/(?<=\d?\.\d*)\..*/g`

You need to use `*` (include 0 to x elements of this character) instead of `+` (include 1 to x of this character)

I have added a `?` after your first `\d` to handle the case if it starts with a `.` and not a digit.

Comment: @Amessihel Open the demo in Chrome and you will see no issue. However, the pattern in this answer is not correct, since `(?<=\d?\.\d*)\..*` [does not match all string beginning with the second dot](https://regex101.com/r/3IELC2/5).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i bow to the master. :)

Comment: `/(?<=\w?\.\w*)\..*/` is [still wrong](https://regex101.com/r/3IELC2/7) for an arbitrary string. `(?<=^[^.]*\.[^.]*)\..*` is correct. No `g` modifier is necessary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is why you are the regex master. and I'm a humble padawan. :)

Answer (score 0):

When reading your question literally.

> I want to match everything beginning from second `.`, including `.`

This would do the trick:

```
[.][^.]*([.].*)
```

Leaving the resulting answer in group 1. Keep in mind that `[^.]` also matches newline characters, if you don't want this add `\n` to the character negation class.